# how can i insert two different form using one controller method by one trigger in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have try but, i want to do it with ajax on click one button, want to send two form value to table using one method bu controller in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose these are your forms

```
<form name="frm1" id="frm1">
    <input type="text" name="txt1" >
    <input type="text" name="txt2">

</form>

<form name="frm2" id="frm2">
    <input type="text" name="txt3" >
    <input type="text" name="txt4">

</form>

<button type="button" id="btn">Submit</button>
```

Ajax Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var BASE_URL = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#btn" ).click(function() {
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
               url:BASE_URL + "Controller/save",
              data: $('#frm1, #frm2').serialize(),
              success: function (data) {
               data = JSON.parse(data);
               console.log(data);     
            }
          });
    });
});

</script>
```

By this in the save method you can get the values of the forms in controller

```
function save()
    {
        echo $this->input->post('txt1');
        echo $this->input->post('txt2');
        echo $this->input->post('txt3');
        echo $this->input->post('txt4');
    }
```